# How to check the log of TOC layer in ArcMap, like "Results - Current Session"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, log, results-window

I use ArcMap version 10.2.

I want to check the usage history of the layer in Table Of Contents.
(Add layers, delete layers, check layers, etc.)

Is there a function or page that allows to check history like the ArcMap Results Session?

How can I check my layer history?

Comment: Those changes aren't tracked, except by undo/redo and that only lasts until you save, and I don't expect layer/element changes to be tracked in the latest desktop or pro.